# Windows Linux Subsystem: start Bash Application as a Service

Tags: windows, autostart, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As the title already summarizes:

How can I start a bash-script automatically, when the computer starts - ideally without the need to log in to windows - using the Microsoft Subsystem for Linux's Bash.

Comment: Bash is just an executable, right, you don't need to do anything special to launch it?  [nssm](http://nssm.cc/) should work.  Or you could use Microsoft's srvany.  There are probably other third-party solutions too.

Comment: ok, how does it work exactly? I have a script located in `/mnt/c/Users/<myuser>/repos/server/start.sh` 
inside of this script, I do a `cd /mnt/c/Users/<myuser>/repos/server; echo "Started" > somefile.txt; python myserver.py`
The server opens a tcp port 8080 for http. the windows firewall is disabled. I get no conection and no file `somefile.txt`

--- I tried as well with nssm and with the windows task scheduler

Comment: *Theoretically,* if I understand how all this works, if a `bash.exe` command works at the Windows command line, it should also work when run from a service.  Obviously you can't just invoke a bash script directly, you would need to call `bash.exe` with the appropriate command-line options.  Probably the best way to troubleshoot would be to use `psexec` (available from the MS web site) to run your command line, that way you'll see the error message (if any).

Comment: If I run (Win+R) bash.exe "/mnt/c/Users/<myuser>/repos/server/start.sh" the server starts up with no problems. as a nssm or as a task scheduler service - well not. In nssm I get error 0x80070005 inside of the stdout-file, in task scheduler, I get no error at all

Comment: "Access denied."  Are you sure the account nssm is running as has access to your scripts?

Comment: as nssm is running as "system account" I think it should?

Comment: In most scenarios the default permissions grant access to SYSTEM, either directly or via the Administrators group.  But I don't know how Ubuntu-on-Windows sets file permissions for files and/or directories it creates, so it might be worth double-checking.

Comment: ok, I wrapped the call inside of a batch file and now recognize that it is indeed the start of the bash.exe that has a problem and returns `Fehler: 0x80070005` also a `psexec -s ...myscript.bat` (instead of running it as a service) produces the same problem. It produces the problem, when the Script runs ad Admin, as System and as my User (that ownes the file) but when I run the batch-file directly, it works.

Comment: If you use `psexec -s` to run `bash.exe` without any options, does it do the same thing?  If so, it might be a limitation of Ubuntu-on-Windows itself.  You could perhaps try Process Monitor as a troubleshooting tool, see if you can tell exactly what is returning the access denied error.

Comment: jap, it also gives the same error: `psexec -s "bash.exe"`returns -1 and prints `F e h l e r :   0 x 8 0 0 7 0 0 0 5`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, this isn't supported, because the WSL session manager service will close after the last bash.exe wrapper instance closes. There are a few options, but the absolute simplest one at the moment is to use the [run utility](http://www.straightrunning.com/projectrun/) from the Xming developer and just add a shortcut to your startup folder (in the start menu) pointing to

`run.exe bash.exe -c "/home/user/daemoninit.sh ; /bin/bash"`.  Unfortunately, if your daemon initialization requires root access, for example, something like sshd, you will need to add an exception to sudoers that allows anybody to run the daemon with root privileges.

Also, there are problems getting it to run as a true Windows system service, since each lxss installation is user-specific.  Some people have gotten it to run on system startup, but it launches in a separate Windows session for that user and makes it so you can't launch bash.exe in your current user session.

Comment: Well, the not being able to open another bash window sounds not so bad if you could use putty to ssh into it and you're done I think